# Android - trying to stop ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: android, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm using the next code at on create method of an activity -

```
        scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);


    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.eample.one.services.action.check");
       startService(intent);
      }
    }, 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

As you can see I'm calling with it to a service every 5 seconds.

I've declared the service at the manifest like so -

```
  <service
        android:name="com.eample.one.services.CheckService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.eample.one.services.action.check" />

        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Now at the same activity, which I've declared the ScheduledExecutorService, I have an exit button.

When pressing on it I've tried to stop the ScheduledExecutorService , like so -

```
    scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdownNow(); 
            finish();
```

Or even

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown(); 
   finish();
```

finish() is of course to finish the activity.

But the thing is that scheduleTaskExecutor wouldn't stop after pressing on that button.

Any ideas why is that?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Have you tried cancelling the `Future` that is returned from `scheduleAtFixedRate`? Although I'd imagine `shutdownNow` would do that for you.

Comment: what you mean in Future ?

Comment: Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) for the method you're calling. That method returns a `ScheduledFuture` which has a [`cancel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method.

Comment: well maybe - but when i try to do ScheduledFuture.cancel(); - it says that ScheduledFuture don't have this option

Comment: `Future future = scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);`
`future.cancel();`

Comment: Well first of all future.cancel(); - need to get a boolean value - so I've tried this one - future.cancel(true); - Not working - still the service runing at the backrground

Comment: Yeah, forgot about the boolean arg. Anyway, this doesn't stop the service, it just (hopefully) stops the `Executor`. You still need to stop the actual service yourself (if necessary). Also, scheduling the `Executor` in `onCreate` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Well I've move it to the on resume also added to the onclick of the exit button - the next line -stopService(new Intent("at.vcity.androidim.services.action.groupmsgcheck")); - and it doesn't work. It seems like the timer aspect neede to be stop - but i sure don't understand how and why it dosen't stop

Answer (score 0):

The doc for [ExecutorService.shutdownNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) contains this paragraph:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate.

Since your Runnable is starting an Android service (in the new thread), the service should test

> Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()

periodically and exit if that is true.

Comment: Well don't know how to stop it - I've tried also - stopService(new Intent(this,CheckService.class)); - But it won't stop

Comment: Is that exactly the same Intent that you used to start the service? A service can also stop itself via Service.stopSelf(). See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf().

Comment: Ok , I've started the service with this line right - Intent intent = new Intent("com.eample.one.services.action.check"); - So if I wnat to stop it with this line - stopService(new Intent(this,CheckService.class)); - Is there other way to do so ?

Comment: Try stopService(new Intent("com.eample.one.services.action.check")).

Comment: Well tried it - it still runing after i press on the exit button

Comment: The service may not exit for a number of reasons. If you do a search for "android stopSevice does not stop", you'll see a lot of prior questions related to this.